# Create a mask from a matrix

Tags: python

Hi there i got a Matrix like this

```
A=[[nan, 4, nan],[3 , 7 , 8],[nan, 23, nan]]
```

and I would like to get a mask from the the Matrix A, that is as follows

```
mask=[[nan, 0, nan],[0, 0, 0],[nan, 0, nan]]
```

for that I have tried:

```
import numpy as np
A=[[nan, 4, nan],[3 , 7 , 8],[nan, 23, nan]]
mask=A
mask[np.isfinite(A)]=0
```

But this also deletes the numerical values of the Matrix A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a copy of A in order to keep the values in A, see: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

In your case this would be

```
A=[[nan, 4, nan],[3 , 7 , 8],[nan, 23, nan]]
mask=np.array(A.copy())
mask[~np.isnan(A)] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html), in order to mask those values that aren't `np.nan`, and fill the masked array with `0`:

```
A = np.array([[np.nan, 4, np.nan],[3 , 7 , 8],[np.nan, 23, np.nan]])
np.ma.masked_array(A, mask = ~np.isnan(A)).filled(0)

array([[nan,  0., nan],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [nan,  0., nan]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `A[~np.isnan(A)]`:

```
from numpy import *  

A=[[NaN, 4, NaN],[3 , 7 , 8],[NaN, 23, NaN]]    
A = np.array(A)
A[~np.isnan(A)] = 0

print(A)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[[nan  0. nan]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [nan  0. nan]]
```